# AIRE processing while on UK temporary visa

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, citizenship, italian-citizens, italy-aire

My girlfriend is Brazilian and is finishing obtaining her Italian citizenship. She is currently in the UK under a temporary 6 months visa (currently on the 2nd month).

Her Italian Citizenship is just the documents that prove she is an Italian Citizen; thus, after that, she still needs to request her travel documents and for that she must register on AIRE to request Italian documents here in the UK.

Is it possible for her to register on AIRE in the UK under a 6 months visitor/tourist visa? We intend to relocate to UK and going back to Brazil just to wait the AIRE process and apply for an Italian passport would be too lengthy.

I don’t see why there would be any problem is this scenario but I want to make sure this is possible. Note that AIRE has a maximum processing time of 180 days, although it typically goes much faster depending on the italian comune. I am also not sure if there's a way of requesting a visa extension just to wait for AIRE and her italian passport/ID, since she would already have her italian citizenship documents ready (thus being an EU citizen, but without her travel documents).

If anyone can help me with any input it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As enrolment in AIRE asks for proof of residence, it may be difficult to do so while in the UK on a tourist/visitor visa: [it is necessary (but not obligatory) that the enrolee display a document proving residence in the chosen foreign municipality](http://www.esteri.it/mae/en/italiani_nel_mondo/serviziconsolari/aire.html) (e.g. certificate of residence issued by the foreign authority, residence permit, identity card, utility bills, copy of the employment contract etc.). Has she contact the Consulate in the UK?

Comment: OP has not returned to answer @Dorothy's question, closing as unclear.